# Updating live tiles from Background audio agent?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Updating live tiles from Background audio agent?

I know that you can update Liva Tils with ShellTile of PeriodicTask. is it possible to update the live tiles of background audio agent?

I want to do, for example, when the track changed to the title track on the live tile. Is this possible?

Just did not want to do would have been a few applications of background agents: agent audio and even periodic background agent. Would not this heavy load and impact on battery life?

Update:
BackgroundAudioPlayer tried in this way:

```
ShellTile apptile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
            StandardTileData appTileData = new StandardTileData();
            appTileData.Title = "Title App";
            appTileData.Count = 5;
            appTileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("/front.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            apptile.Update(appTileData);
```

And I get an error message `First()` is not found

Comment: Try before asking? And if you tried, tell us why it didn't work. No point asking *us* to go try it for you, and tell you if it's not possible.

Comment: Did you include the System.Linq namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file.